# FileNotFound exception when trying to read and write

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, syntax-error

on one of my Java homework assignments, I am asked to request 2 file names from a user,  copy all the text from the first file, and then convert it all to uppercase letters and write it to the second file.

I have my reading and writing methods copied almost exactly as it is in my book, but I can not compile because I am getting the error that the file is not found. I have even tried removing the part where the user assigns the file names and just added the directory and file location myself but I am still getting the FileNotFound Exception.

The errors appear on lines 17 and 32.

Is there something I am doing wrong or is there a problem with Netbeans?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StockdaleUpperfile {


public static void main(String[] args) {
     String readFile, writeFile, trash;
     String line, fileContents, contentsConverted;

     System.out.println("Enter 2 file names.");
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     readFile = keyboard.nextLine();
     writeFile = keyboard.nextLine();

     File myFile = new File(readFile);
     Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);  //unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown;

     line = inputFile.nextLine();
     fileContents=line;

     while(inputFile.hasNext())
     {
         line = inputFile.nextLine();
         fileContents+=line;
     }
     inputFile.close();

     contentsConverted = fileContents.toUpperCase();


     PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter(writeFile);  //Isn't this supposed to create a file if it doesn't detect one?
     outputfile.println(contentsConverted);
     outputfile.close();

     }


    }
}
```

Comment: What input do you provide when u run the program ? it should be a absolute path to the file something like `c:/Users/file.txt`

Comment: I have tried typing the directory address like that. My biggest concern is, shouldn't PrintWriter create a file even if it doesn't exist?

Comment: input the file path as follows: `C://folder//file.txt`

Comment: I did this @VishalK but it still did not work. I added my results in the comment below the first answer.

Comment: Try to do the same but this time with other Directory Like `D://file.txt`

Comment: I did as you suggested but am receiving the same error :/

Comment: what I think that you are inputting the file path as "`c://folder//file.txt`" . Remove this sign (`"`) before and after the pathName.

Comment: When I remove the (`"`) it says I am using illegal characters. I thought that it was required unless using a variable name?

Comment: I think that you are inputting the file name via command line..!!! because u are using `Scanner(System.in)` to read filenames.....

Answer (score 0):

Change the method as

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
```

Comment: Adding throws Exception allows it to compile, but I still get the FileNotFound when it reaches that part of the code.

I created a folder in C: called folder and placed a file in it called file.txt.

I changed `File myFile = new File("C:\\folder\\file.txt");`


Yet I am still getting this error 

    `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\folder\file.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)`

Comment: Works fine for me. Make sure the file exists and the directory has read write permissions.

Comment: If you are on Windows, trying writing to your home directory (go to run and type %home% )